# Is it possible to play m3u8 links using ExoPlayer?

Tags: exoplayer, m3u8

After trying multiple ways of playing m3u8 files using videoview and mediaplayer I decided to give up. Everytime i play the m3u8 file I only hear the voice.(please dont write urls from stack overflow answering my question. I' ve red them all ) Been asking around ,finally got to know that exoplayer maybe is the one I'm looking for. However exoplayer seems to be a newbie and I can'n find any proper tutorial. That been said Im myself a newbie and all talks about tracker and blabla seem just too complicated for me. I only want to be able to open all my m3u8 files from different urls in my app without passing them to vlc or any external intents.

For the record I use KitKat and above. So exoplayer should be implementable.

So what Im desperatly asking for is a simple tutorial in how I can play my m3u8 files using exoplayer or anyother way that shows the video and play the audio and NOT just one of them. Please dont link me to the exoplayer page on google dev. Ive been there too.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An M3U8 for a video stream almost certainly means the stream is a HLS stream.

It's may be a little more detail that you need but HLS is a streaming protocol can segments a streams media streams - the streams can have different container formats (MP4 etc) and video encoders (h.246 etc) so even if the device and ExoPlayer support HLS, it is possible they may not be able to support the particular codec, for example, that you are using - this is worth checking also.

Android Media support information is available here:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats

ExoPlayer was probably more focused on DASH streams than HLS previously, but the short answer to your question is that Yes, ExoPLayer can play HLS streams and there is available documentation to support this, including examples.

The best place for you to start is likely here:

- https://exoplayer.dev/hls.html